# 2015 Nissan sentra- a/c only blows cold at highway speeds

Tags: ac, troubleshooting, nissan

I have a 2015 nissan sentra. When i first got it in 2015 it had one of the best ac systems i had ever had the pleasure of using, like too cold in 105 degree heat on the minimum setting.

Then after about a couple years a lady on her cell phone caused a 6 car pile-up and i was car number 4. We took it to a body shop that was at her insurance company's same building, which was fine with me because it was just down the street and had a good reputation.

Well after theu had it for a month I got tired of the rental (2015 corolla), so I called them and said I wanted to pick it up. It had been far too long, the guy said you cant its not done.

so i asked what still needed to be done and he said just the badges. I told him not to worry about it that it doesn't matter to me, he still got upset about it and eventually said look man it's my car im coming to get it badges or not and id sign something saying it was done to my liking, he got pissy and said fine it will be put front. I pickedit up and didnt notice for a couple days because it was mainly highway driving i was doing at the time, but i noticed that it just didnt blow as cold as it used to before the shop had it, and that it slowly started cooling less and less in city driving conditions, todau it was 106 degrees and I am only in city driving conditions these days and the air coming out is about the same as the air temp outside maybe a little bit cooler but definitely not cooling at a satisfactory level. When i drive highway speeds its get cold and is bareably cool but still no where near as cold as it used to be.

Do you think the guy let out some freon to get me back for picking up my car before he wanted me to? What can i do to find out if its got a low charge without gauges? And what other things could be contributing factors or causes? Sorry my question is so long but i feel like the more info the better advice or dianosis you all can give.

Comment: Looks like a damaged condenser to me. Can you look at it and check for wet spots (compressor oil patches)?

Comment: Forgot an important thing: avoid using the AC in the meanwhile, until you've found the problem. Very low refrigerant can deprive the compressor of lubrication, damage it and make it seize. Automotive AC compressors, unlike bus ones, don't have a separate oil sump and dedicated pump and therefore rely on correct refrigerant level (making any discharged oil correctly return to the compressor) for lubrication.

Comment: Check freon level if its low it will cause this

Answer (score 0):

Check if the fans run while the a/c is turned on. Highway speed will generate enough airflow to pull the heat from the system, but lower speeds and sitting require the assistance of the fan.

Comment: Inoperative fans would indeed impair cooling when the vehicle is stopped. But the OP complained that even while moving, the a/c is only cool, and not cold. Thus, there is something else wrong with the a/c system too.

Answer (score 0):

If the compressor cycles on and off (it's a clicking sound) in a fast cycle, you're probably low.

But I really recommend that you get a gauge. You can get a can of r134a which includes a gauge from Wal-Mart for ~$20. Connect to the low pressure port, start the engine running with the A/C on full, and see if the the needle goes to green. If the needle isn't in the green, add refrigerant. (There are a lot of YouTube videos for how to refill your A/C.) That will keep you cool while you find a repair shop to find the leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the blower motor resistor pack.

The fan will only work on maximum speed, if resistor is bad.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The fan will only run on high with a bad resistor, but this doesn't affect the A/C components besides the fan. Really, this doesn't answer the question which was given. Please take [The Tour](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) for tips on how to answer questions.